# Не работает satisfy any в конфиге apache

Tags: apache, apache2.2

Я пытаюсь полностью закрыть доступ к файлам ".log|.yaml|.yml|.sql" и оставить доступ к остальным файлам по HTTP Auth или для отдельных IP адресов, по отдельности правила работают, но опция satisfy any все ломает filesmatch просто игнорируется.

Что неправильно делаю?

```
<Directory "/var/www/test.com">

    <FilesMatch ".log|.yaml|.yml|.sql">
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Dev"
    AuthUserFile "/var/data/passwds/test.com"
    Require valid-user
    order deny,allow
    allow from 1.2.3.4
    satisfy any

</Directory>
```